# Programming a graceful fall-back from JS to non-JS experience

Tags: javascript, html

I am a web developer and created a non-JS social networking website where everything works perfectly for devices not employing JS, including form submission (lots of page refreshes).

Who is using non-JS devices in this day and age? A non-trivial chunk of my users.

Why are they using non-JS devices? Because they originate from a forward proxy that removes JavaScript. Or, some of them have non-smart feature phones where JS doesn't exist.

---

The navbar of my website currently looks like this:

[image]

I recently had it redesigned to this scrolling experience:

[image]

Is it possible to create an experience such that JS supporting devices see the latest navbar, whereas all other devices keep on seeing the old `static` navbar?

If so, how? Can someone give me a basic example of how to do this?

---

Note: I'm aware that pure CSS solutions exist too, in which case JS doesn't even enter the discussion. However, such a solution could still potentially exclude my most primitive device users. The best solution for me would definitely need some kind of a 'fallback' to the static navbar. Please advise accordingly.

Comment: You can use [the `<noscript>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript), for example.

Comment: `<noscript> Your browser does not support javascript which is needed to display this page. You could however visit the <a href="/fallback/">old version</a></noscript>`

Comment: CSS can degrade very gracefully, very easily, and it seems like a great option. Are you targeting browsers that doesn't support CSS at all?

Comment: Or you add the menus with JavaScript so it gets the dynamic content.

Comment: @RomanCortes: No, I don't think there's a device in existence that doesn't support CSS at all (or maybe there is, I don't know). I'm more concerned about the case where the device doesn't support the latest CSS3/HTML5 goodness like most modern browsers do.

Comment: @Jonasw: So in other words, use the `<noscript>` tag to notify the user what's going on. Btw how about using media queries? Most of the primitive sets are also small-screen sized sets. Could you give me an example of media queries I can use in that case?

Comment: @hassan na that would be buggy. I think having a separate fallback page is the best option. The only drawback is that you have to keep two different pages up to date...

Comment: @jonasw: well that, and the fact that users would have to manually opt-into falling back, instead of automatically/gracefully falling back to the static design.

Comment: Why not using css classes (js, no-js) and dependency css? That's "supported" since the early beginnings and then show the menu in dependency of the given class at html-tag. That's the usual way. Why does this not work for you?

Comment: @JoshuaK: could you give a small illustrative example as an answer? Maybe I'm not seeing what you're saying because of my primarily webdev, server and sysadmin background. Let's drill into it.

Comment: @HassanBaig I have to go now, but if there is no answer later, I will give you a full example code. It's very easy and common. Sorry, but later, ok?

Comment: @JoshuaK: sure, I mean I do think I know what you mean, but I do want you to flesh it out for me, I have some issues with that approach. Later then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can provide two different sites and use the `noscript`-tag to tell the user he or she should take the other page if javascript is not available.

The better way in my opinion is to build the switch inside the code and only show the content that is ideal for the current user.

The common way to achieve this is the following:

1. Add the css class `no-js` to the `html`-tag
2. Add a small javascript script portion that removes this css class (or replaces it with `js`
3. build your css like always but if you want to provide different stylings (or hide / show specific elements) prepend the css declaration with `.no-js` or `.js`

In your case you could have both navigations inside your html markup and display only the navigation that suits the current user.

This "trick" works btw with every switch you want to build (for css rules). If you want to build a cool font effect and set the color to the background color and add a shadow it's realy bad if the shadow is not visible because the users browser is not able to understand the text-shadow css rule. So you can build it with a fallback like this:

```
.cool-font-effect {
  color:black;
}
.textshadow .cool-font-effect {
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px silver;
}
```

and use js to detect if the users browser can use text-shadow:

```
var isTextShadowSupported = ()=>document.createElement("detect").style.textShadow==="";
if(isTextShadowSupported())
  document.querySelector('html').classList.add('textshadow');
```

BTW: This is the way [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) works. If you like that and don't want to build all the tests yourself take a look at it. Th tests are fast and you can test against nearly every feature in html, css and javascript.